# Call back to Shared Application from Target Application in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a browser application that allows me to store files in the local space and displays a list of all the files present.

My application can be considered a sharing application.

Now in my application as soon as i click on a file, the file is opened in a target application, for example if i click on a PDF document, the file is opened by the Acrobat Reader Application.

I am trying to detect a call back inside my sharing application from the target application, triggered as soon as the user closes the target application that currently is displaying a file that is only present in my local app space.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand what you are trying to achieve is to find a trigger which informs that your application is again visible to user now. For this you you can use *VisibilityChanged* event like this

Window.Current.VisibilityChanged += Current_VisibilityChanged;

and also if your app was suspended by the OS then you need to handle this in App.Xaml.cs in *OnActivated* event or create a new event for app resuming available in *this.Resuming*

Comment: Hi @Rohit, 

My primary motive is to be notified (in my application) as soon as the target application is done processing with a file that is present in my app's local (i.e. the target application which is invoked from my application has been closed.)